# What are the default DifferenceListener & matchTracker used by Diff of XMLUnit?

Tags: xmlunit

Default ElementQualifier is ElementNameQualifier, but what are the default DifferenceListener & MatchTracker?

Answer (score 1):

`Diff` itself implements `DifferenceListener` and uses itself as default, there is no default `MatchTracker` at all.